# Why did Ben Bradlee specifically mention "91 words a minute"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-post

The Post's managing editor, Ben Bradlee reads a paper:

> BEN: All these guys sound like they sleep with a damn thesaurus. So
>   McNaughton was secretly suggesting to McNamara...to provoke the  North
>   so we'd have grounds for escalation?
>
> CHALMERS: Yep. Yeah, it was in The Times article. It was a good piece.
>   You should check it out. It was well-written.
>
> (*Ben shows middle finger to Chalmers*)
>
> Ben hands a paper to another man that he had just read  and says:
>
> Ben: Give it to someone who can't type **91 words a minute**... and have
>   it proofed, okay?

Why did Ben Bradlee specifically mention "91 words a minute"?

Comment: It's probably just meant to be a random fast typing speed. Seems to me he feels like the piece in question was written by someone who is too good of a writer - they wrote it in such an intellectual style that the piece would be too hard to understand for a typical reader. Whoever wrote it was able to make it overly wordy in a short amount of time because they can type so fast. So by giving it to someone who types slower, that person will have to make it shorter and less wordy in order to finish it in a reasonable amount of time. Commenting because it's just a guess.